# Where is the circular reference?

Tags: python, json, object, serialization

I'm writing some python classes that I want to encode into JSON.  When I try to jsonify my objects, I get an error mentioning a 'circular reference'.  I think I understand what a circular reference means, but I can't find any examples in my code.

### The relationship (has a/is a) between the objects

- Signup has a
- Registrant has a
- Address

### Code (python):

```
class Address:
    def __init__(self, address1, address2, city, state, zip):
        self.address1 = address1
        self.address2 = address2
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zip = zip

class Signup:
    def __init__(self, registrant, classId, date, time, paid, seatCost, notes, className, seats, groupId, agentName, agentCompany):
        self.registrant = registrant
        self.classId = classId
        self.date = date
        self.time = time
        self.paid = paid
        self.seatCost = seatCost
        self.notes = notes
        self.className = className
        self.seats = seats
        self.groupId = groupId
        self.agentName = agentName
        self.agentCompany = agentCompany

class Registrant:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, address, phone, email):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email

def scrape(br):
    signups = []

    soup = libStuff.getSoup(br, 'http://thepaintmixer.com/admin/viewdailysignups.php')

    table = soup.find(id='Calendar')
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    rowNumber = 0
    for row in rows:
        if rowNumber == 0:
            rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
            continue
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        cellNumber = 0
        for cell in cells:
            if cellNumber == 0:
                try:
                    firstName = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    firstName = None
            elif cellNumber == 1:
                try:
                    lastName = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    lastName = None
            elif cellNumber == 2:
                try:
                    address1 = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    address1 = None
            elif cellNumber == 3:
                try:
                    address2 = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    address2 = None
            elif cellNumber == 4:
                try:
                    city = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    city = None
            elif cellNumber == 5:
                try:
                    state = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    state = None
            elif cellNumber == 6:
                try:
                    zip = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    zip = None
            elif cellNumber == 7:
                try:
                    phone = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    phone = None
            elif cellNumber == 8:
                try:
                    email = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    email = None
            elif cellNumber == 9:
                try:
                    classId = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    classId = None
            elif cellNumber == 10:
                try:
                    date = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    date = None
            elif cellNumber == 11:
                try:
                    time = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    time = None
            elif cellNumber == 12:
                try:
                    paid = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    paid = None
            elif cellNumber == 13:
                try:
                    seatCost = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    seatCost = None
            elif cellNumber == 14:
                try:
                    notes = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    notes = None
            elif cellNumber == 15:
                try:
                    className = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    className = None
            elif cellNumber == 16:
                try:
                    seats = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    seats = None
            elif cellNumber == 17:
                try:
                    groupId = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    groupId = None
            elif cellNumber == 18:
                try:
                    agentName = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    agentName = None
            elif cellNumber == 19:
                try:
                    agentCompany = cell.contents[0]
                except IndexError:
                    agentCompany = None
            cellNumber = cellNumber + 1

        address = Address(address1, address2, city, state, zip)
        registrant = Registrant(firstName, lastName, address, phone, email)
        signup = Signup(registrant, classId, date, time, paid, seatCost, notes, className, seats, groupId, agentName, agentCompany)
        signups.append(signup)
    return signups
#I then call json.dumps() on that returned list
json.dumps(scrape(br), default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

Are my constructors messed up?  Am I passing something I shouldn't?

Comment: You just showed the classes, but not what you're doing with them.  Please show a simple example of how you're using the classes and what error is generated.

Comment: @BrenBarn Ok, but it is a lot of code

Comment: Then make a smaller, simpler example that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know where the problem is so I don't know what I can remove.

Comment: @macsj200 Consider using [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) to represent your data.  All that copy/pasting is really complicating your search for your solution and really stops us from getting you help.

Comment: I'm still working on implementing it, so I don't know if it's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The likely cause is that `cell.contents[0]` is returning a complex BeautifulSoup object rather than straight text.  The BeautifulSoup objects know their parents, siblings, parser class, attribute, and other objects that might be shared or circular.

The situation arises when a `<td>` element contains inner html.  This is common in tables (perhaps a table entry is bolded or italicized for example).

A likely solution to your problem is to make sure to use BeautifulSoup's `.text` to make sure you're only getting text and not inner BeautifulSoup elements:

```
columns = [col.text for col in row.findAll('td')]
```

FWIW, here is an easy diagnostic technique to see what is actually going on.  Just modify the default function in the *json.dumps()* to make its output visible:

```
def view_dict(obj):
    print '--------------'
    print 'Type:', obj.__class__
    d = obj.__dict__
    pprint.pprint(d)
    return d

json.dumps(scrape(br), default=view_dict)
```

The circular reference should pop right out.  Hope this clears up the mystery (because otherwise your code looks fine and is not explicitly creating circular references).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the error, so I refactored to use named tuples (Credit @metatoaster).  Re-factoring fixed the problem.

```
def scrape(br):
    signups = []

    soup = libStuff.getSoup(br, 'http://thepaintmixer.com/admin/viewdailysignups.php')

    table = soup.find(id='Calendar')
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    rowNumber = 0
    for row in rows:
        if rowNumber == 0:
            rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
            continue
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        cells = [cell.string if cell.string != None else '' for cell in cells]
        signup = Signup(*cells)
        signups.append(signup)
    return signups
```

Comment: You should at least run the diagnostic in the other answer to confirm what the actual cause was.  That way, this SO question and answer will be useful to others.

Comment: FWIW, the actual fix was likely the ``.string`` part.  The other changes were nice code improvements but had nothing to do with your circular references.